# Remove the spaces from a string

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a string `'test                '`. I Am trying to remove the space. I have used `RTrim` function. but its not working. Please help.

Comment: "but its not working" - you will need to explain better than that.

Comment: What kind of field is it? `char` or `varchar`? Are you sure those are spaces and not some other characters that just display as space?

Comment: I just executed the following statement in 
SQL 2008 and it worked fine: SELECT 
 RTRIM('BRONX                ')
 ,LEN(RTRIM('BRONX                '))
 ,LEN('BRONX')

Comment: @HansKesting, sorry! I have posted my answer before read your comment. Do you want I remove it? I think I precipitate.

Comment: @HansKesting, does not matter, removed. I think that user should answer this comments before an answer be posted.

Comment: Hi,Actually the string is consists of the ascii charecters which are not visible.If there are spaces then Rtrim is working.Please could you please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because `RTrim` removes trailing whitespace but you don't have any whitespace after `'`.

Try `SELECT REPLACE('BRONX                ', ' ', '')`

Answer (score 0):

Probably it is not space. Copy character and paste it to `REPLACE(string,HERE,'')`

Here is some code:

```
DECLARE @string as nvarchar(50);
SET @string = 'dbc      '
SELECT RTRIM(@string)
SELECT REPLACE(@string,' ','')
```

Comment: The last character is a `'`. You can see this in his question.

Answer (score 0):

If you column is a `char` (or `nchar`) column and you are trying to remove spaces by something like:

```
update MyTable
  set MyColumn = RTrim(MyColumn)
```

that will not work. See [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175055.aspx):

> The char data type is a fixed-length data type when the NOT NULL
>   clause is specified. If a value shorter than the length of the column
>   is inserted into a char NOT NULL column, the value is right-padded
>   with blanks to the size of the column. For example, if a column is
>   defined as char(10) and the data to be stored is "music", SQL Server
>   stores this data as "music_*_*_", where "_" indicates a blank space.

Comment: It will not work because the last character is a `'`. You can see this in his question.

Comment: @todda.speot.is - or did he just mean the regular string demiliter to show the spaces? I understood it as such.